# Testing Paypal Express in ActiveMerchant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, activemerchant

How can I test Paypal Express with ActiveMerchant in a Rails 3.2 app with rspec/capybara integration test?

Comment: http://www.codyfauser.com/2008/1/17/paypal-express-payments-with-activemerchant ?

Comment: @RobZolkos did you manage to achieve this? I'm trying to do it now, not sure how.

Comment: Unfortunately, this URL no longer exists. Any hints to where to find docs or a tutorial on rspec'ing active_merchant's paypal express gateway would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can test by setting:

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
```

**PayPal** however will require you to enter complete billing information or the API won't even accept it and will return:

**Error: There's an error with this transaction. Please enter a complete billing address.**

In which case you can supply it with some generic info:

```
:billing_address => {
    :name     => "Test Person",
    :address1 => "123 W 423 E",
    :city     => "Somewhere",
    :state    => "CA",
    :country  => "US",
    :zip      => "88888"
 }
```

Comment: I'm aware of how to activate test mode with the gateway.  My question was how I write an automated integration test with rspec/capybara.